# How to clear export_module for a view

Tags: views, chaos-tool-suite

I am unable to export a particular view via Features UI because this view is supposedly default by a different module. In features.ctools.inc line 164 - 172:

```
// If this object is provided as a default by a different module, don't
      // export and add that module as a dependency instead.
      if (!empty($object->export_module) && $object->export_module !== $module_name) {
        $export['dependencies'][$object->export_module] = $object->export_module;
        if (isset($export['features'][$component][$object_name])) {
          unset($export['features'][$component][$object_name]);
        }
      }
      // Otherwise, add the component.
      else {
        $export['features'][$component][$object_name] = $object_name;
      }
```

As you see from the code, my view is not being exported because it has different 'export_module'. How to clear 'export_module' for a particular view to enable it export via features. 
This is what i did:

1. ensure that the other feature doesn't export this view.
2. Ensured that the setting 'Allow conflicts to be added' is selected.
3. I have cleared cache,
4. Deleted the tables cache, cache_view.

No result, the view i like to export via feature continue to come up with 'export_module' different making impossible to export. Any help much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

After removing MODULE-Name_views_default_views() in file MODULE-Name.views_default.inc, the view was exporting in another feature/module just fine.

My learning is that if you rename views that are part of some feature/module say X then these views become impossible to export from any another feature/module Y unless you manually delete them from the MODULE-X-Name_views_default_views() in MODULE-X.views_default.inc file

Answer (score 0):

bum....the same behavior is whenever i have two features exporting the same a variable via strongarm. This is really limiting me having a theme and then multiple different sites extending it....or having module(plugin) to share across multiple sites. Any suggestions how to remove this behavior where its possible to export a variable, view, etc that is shared between two or more features beside changing the core code?